How to read component A's element's property in CSS that belongs to component B in React?
Given a .tsx defines a component A() - that has an element <H> , which height property may change. There is a different .tsx having a component B() that includes CSS x.css and this component B() intends to position an element <E> right below the element <H>.
I intend to employ sticky positions for <E> in x.css and calculate the current height of the <H> element something like this:
.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(var(--ElementH-height));
}

I would need this to make <E> sticky against scrolling.
Can I set this variable in A()'s CSS file and if so, will it keep updating ?
So A.tsx has something like this :
function H() {
    return (
        <header className="header">
           ...
        </header>
    );
}

And B.tsx defines E;
export function E() {
  
  return (
    <FilterContext.Provider value={filters}>
      <div className="sticky-header"> // Shall be right beneath the <header>
        <div className="sticky-header-caption">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    ...
    
    </FilterContext.Provider>
  )
}

After all the question is; how can you fix a sticky element in the middle of screen approx. , which current Y position depends on <H> element's height ?

please add some sample code for components A,B,E and element H
Your ques is difficult to understand

So when H scrolls out of view, E is still there? Is it not weird. I think both of them should be sticky then isn't it?
